# Swift Generics - Allow subclasses passed as parameters

Tags: swift, generics

I'm wondering if it's possible to allow a method to take in any subclass of a generic superclass. I've posted example code of what I'm trying to achieve below.  Hopefully that describes my situation a little better.

```
import UIKit

class SuperDataClass {

}

class SubDataClass: SuperDataClass {

}

class SuperClass<T: SuperDataClass>: UITableViewCell {

}

class SubClass: SuperClass<SubDataClass> {

}

class Example {
    func test(object: SuperClass<SuperDataClass>) {
        print(object)
    }
}

let object = SubClass()
Example().test(object: object)
```

When running this in a playground you'll get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: error: Generics.playground:20:24: error: cannot convert value of type 'SubClass' to expected argument type 'SuperClass<SuperDataClass>'
```

The reason, as far as I can tell, is that the data type is a subclass of the data type expected by the method.

Changing line 15 to

```
class SubClass: SuperClass<SuperDataClass> {
```

Will fix the issue but isn't applicable to the scenario I'm trying to achieve.  I'd like the method to treat any object that is subclassing SuperClass to be handled by this one method. Is this possible? Is there a better setup that I should be using in order to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make `test` generic:

```
class Example {
    func test<T>(object: SuperClass<T>) {
        print(object)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, I'm now curious as to how we could do something similar but for a method that would be returning a similar item.  

I was trying something along the lines of but have yet to figure out the proper way to make this work.  

`func returnType<T: SuperDataClass, U: SuperClass>() -> U<T>.Type {
        return SubClass.self
    }`

Comment: That wouldn't work because `T` and `U` can be any type that satisfies the constraints. What are you trying to do exactly? Also, I suspect this should be a separate question on its own. @Steve

Comment: I would agree, it's a separate question.  Essentially what I was hoping to understand by solving the example above (which your answer did solve) was how I would be able to pass around multiple subclassed versions of one generic super class.  I have multiple tableviewcells each are subclassing one tableviewcell that knows how to lay itself out given data.  The type of data is different for each subclass.  It's pretty elaborate and I'm probably not explaining it well.  Will continue to dig and attempt a new question with a new example in order to solve this.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

SuperClass < SuperDataClass > is not a super class of SuperClass < SubDataClass >, it is a different class using the same generic but not the same associated type.

The fact that the generic's associated type is a subclass of the other does not implicitly make the generic class its ancestor.

For example, if you were to override a method in SuperClass < SubDataClass > (or SubClass), you would be overriding SuperClass < T >, not SuperClass < SuperDataClass >.

In the generic's declaration < T: SuperDataClass > is a constraint for the use of SuperClass, not a hierarchic relationship.